# How to properly implement a matrix multiplication sum

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, graph

I am working with a flattened 10x10 (nxn) adjacency matrix. Lets call this matrix A. This matrix represents a graph, and I want to apply an edge to edge filter. This filter follows this equation:

**F_ij = [ [*sum k=1->n* [A_ik + A_ki] ] - 2A_ij ] * A_ij**

The result should be another 10x10 matrix that basically counts neighbouring edges. I am having trouble getting the correct answer for this. The code that I have is:

```
F = np.zeros([10,10])
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):
        for k in range(10):
            F[i][j] = ((A[j][k] + A[k][j]) - 2*A[i][j])*A[i][j] 

print(F)
```

[This is the graph matrix A going in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvWU5.png)

And the result, F, that im getting is:

[I can already tell this isnt correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lme0r.png)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't there be a `sum` inside that `k` loop? e.g `F[i,j] += ((A[i,k] + A[k,i])...`

Comment: You can use `broadcasting` instead of loops, but you should, for a start, get the loops right.  That's basic python, even if it isn't optimal `numpy`.  `F = ((A+A.T).sum(axis=1)-2*A)*A` is my first try.

Comment: @hpaulj thank you for the helpful comments. I added the summation and now im getting what I want. Although i still have 3 for loops. I'll have to read up about broadcasting to fix it